# When to use a constructor or literal for regular expressions?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, `name` is a local variable.

I found code similar to this on google.

```
var res = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + name).test(class);
```

But I have also been told to use a regex literal like this:

```
var res = /(\s|^) + name/.test(class);
```

Which is correct or better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it with the constructor. The literal can't have variables, everything will be interpreted **literally** so `+` will be a quantifier and `name` will be the string "name".

Also `\\s` is double-escaped because it's inside a string in the constructor, but in literals you only need to escape once `\s`.

You can test this real quick in the browser:

```
var name = 'foo';
var re1 = /\d + name/;
var re2 = new RegExp('\\d'+ name);

console.log(re1); //=> /\d + name/
console.log(re2); //=> /\dfoo/
```

Comment: Still, you can't interpolate a variable in a literal regex. In that second regex `+` will be a quantifier and `name` will be literally "name".

Answer (score 1):

[Regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are easier to read and write as you do not need to string-escape regex escape characters - you can just use them (backslashes, quotes). Also, they are parsed only once during script "compilation" - nothing needs to be executed each time the line is evaluated.

The [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) only needs to be used if you want to build regexes dynamically. That's the case here, since you want to use the `name` variable. A literal cannot work here - the one you have does match one or more blanks and the string `name` *literally*.